# Yui z-index does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, yui

When I have open the popup in the homepage button should ovelap on the popup, these functionality has been working in FF, but in this  given functionality does not working in IE, so how to run this one, any one help me.

```
function launchDisclaimerPopup()
{
      YAHOO.util.Dom.get("view").style.display="block";
      if(!YAHOO.fdds.disclaimerDialog.userDialog){
      YAHOO.fdds.disclaimerDialog.userDialog = new YAHOO.widget.Dialog("view",
      {
            width: "800px",
            height:"434px",
            fixedcenter:false,          
            position:'relative',
            zindex: 1012,
            context:"tl",
            visible: true,
            constraintoviewport:false,
            iframe:true
      });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it should be `z-index`, not `zindex`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function launchDisclaimerPopup()
{
      YAHOO.util.Dom.get("view").style.display="block";
      if(!YAHOO.fdds.disclaimerDialog.userDialog){
      YAHOO.fdds.disclaimerDialog.userDialog = new YAHOO.widget.Dialog("view",
      {
            width: "800px",
            height:"434px",
            fixedcenter:false,          
            position:'relative',
            z-index: 1012,
            context:"tl",
            visible: true,
            constraintoviewport:false,
            iframe:true
      });
}
```